# multiple spans in a charsequence

Tags: android

when ever I set a span in a charsequence, then set the text in a text view its fine, it comes out right. I am using this

Ssb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), start, end, 1);

Then set the text of the TextView.

But when I get the text from the text view and then get the text from it using tv.getText(); it returns the CharSequence expected but when I set the span somewhere else in the cs the other span when the text is set it's not there.

Im sorry for lack of code. I have no proper internet access at home so im posting this from my phone.

Comment: Do you have any filters attached to the TextView? Also, if you don't modify the text but just turn around and set it again (e.g., `tv.setText(tv.getText());`), does the original span still go away?

Comment: It doesn't remove the spans when I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Spannable mSpannable = textview.getText(); // will hold old spans.
mSpannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), start, end, 1); // do some new span
```

Comment: Thanks. I moved my code around just before to set the text. It was just the way I was doing it. This is basically how im doing it now. Just need to figure out how to save it into a shared preference.